# Unable to access GRUB in Win10/Ubuntu18.04 legacy dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, live-usb, bios

I've installed Windows 10 Pro & Ubuntu 18.04 on primary partitions on a Dell Opti-Plex 7010. I made sure to use legacy BIOS for OS installations on account of having partitioned the hard drive using Ubuntu Live's GParted (MBR). After finishing the Ubuntu installation the PC doesn't enter GRUB when booting, it just boots Windows. I think I created the 18.04 bootable USB about a year ago from 16.04, I don't quite remember the settings (if there were any). I don't know if this should make a difference when I installed this attempted dual boot selecting legacy BIOS.

Comment: Did you install Windows before or after you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: I partitioned the drive from Ubuntu Live, then I installed Windows, and then I installed Ubuntu starting from a graphical interface from the bootable USB, not from the grub text-interface I'm used to from 16.04.

Comment: sounds like you either didn't install grub at all, or you installed it somewhere other than the boot partition. There's a helpful documentation at the following link on how to reinstall Grub from a live Ubuntu instance: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows